# Join a subset of the elements in an array

Tags: php

I have an array with 10 strings in it. How do I join say the first three strings, putting a space between them. For example:

```
"one", "t w o", "three", "four"

->

"one t w o three"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [implode()](http://php.net/implode) after [array_slice()](http://php.net/array_slice) is one quick way:

```
$string = implode(' ', array_slice($array, 0, 3), $array);
```

Or (not my preferred):

```
$string = implode(' ', array_chunk($array, 3)[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_slice`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to extract a part on the array and [`implode`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join it:

```
php> implode(' ', array_slice([ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four' ], 0, 3));
'one two three'
```